# TextView Cannot Be Resolved

Tags: android, textview

Now I know these are fairly common issues, but I'm using a textview that cannot be resolved. I've cleaned the project, import android.widget.TextView, but it continues to flag as unresolved.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://1.php");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            TextView.append(line);
        } 

    }
```

TextView in activity_main:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10">



    </TextView>
```

Any ideas on this please?

EDIT:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

String line = ""; 
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
    TextView1.append(line);
}
```

The end line starting with TextView1 is providing the error stating it cannot be resolved. Just the `TextView1` though, not the entire line.

EDIT 28/10/2012:

Ok, so the TextView is now working, but in turn, other parts of the code are not. This is a screenshot showing exactly what. I can wrap each of these in a try and catch statement but then the app force closes on my Android device.

http://southwestdesign.org.uk/Code.jpg

Any ideas on this one please?

Comment: `TextView.append(line);` : Class `TextView` does not have a static method `append(String)`

Comment: Have you tried moving the code into onStart() ?

Comment: Same error Pete, I hadn't expected this - supposed to be a Uni project and can't really change at this stage. Any help really is appreciated folks.

Comment: The issue will be because you're extending SmallApplication. A number of methods/code will require you to extend Activity instead In this case you might want to try creating an activity instance.

Answer (score 18):

Did you import textview?

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Comment: Technically as of nouget 7.0 this is not the way you would import it but your sentiment is correct and importing the correct TextView is the issue.  I believe this is an ide (Android Studio) is the issue.  I will post  a more complete answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to fetch your specific TextView:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    textView.append(line);
}
```

(You really should give the TextView a unique and more descriptive id, like `android:id="@+id/webContentTV"`. This way when you use 10-20 TextViews you can easily keep track of them.)

---

**Addition**
The `id` in your XML:

```
<!-- Notice I gave this TextView a more descriptive id. -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/webContentTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />
```

*must match* the exact id that you pass to `findViewById()`:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.webContentTV);
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    textView.append(line);
}
```

At the moment your id's don't match: `android:id="TextView"` is not `findViewById(R.id.TextView1)`

Comment: Still the same i'm afraid, have changed the name but the error still persists.

Comment: @PiranSmith: Can you edit the question putting the new code? And tell us where is the error in the new code?

Comment: I've added the code and error to the first post. On a mobile device so its not wrapped in code tags, quite desperate for this I must admit. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have updated the code again showing in a screenshot a new error! grr

Comment: This new question is beyond the scope of the original question, but I'll answer it too. You need to wrap your that all three of those error in one try-catch block, click "quick fix" in the pop up. Soon though you probably get a NetworkOnMainThreadException, when you do [read this article](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. The problem was that I created a project first and then I didn't completed it. So I created a second project. Texview was Texview2 instead and editText was editText2. You might need to update textView to textView2.   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As the poster questions states "TextView" cannot be resolved.  The issue is with where TextView or what TextView is supposed to be resolved.  In this case it is the android.widget.TextView class.

the AS ide doesn't make this to friendly but if you leave the cursor to the very left of the class (literally the left edge of the class it will hint at what you of course mean... android.widget.TextView... you can either type this out yourself or you can hit (windows) alt+ enter and it will set the value correctly to the entire class reference.

when the highlight isn't red then you know it is the correct reference.

to me I prefer to write it out

```
android.widget.TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
```

and know what it is I am referencing and someone else can too.

However, if you want to know for sure the reference is matching up with what you are expecting...

hit/type ctrl+ click on phrase i.e. TextView and it will bring you to the exact java class... in this case via the android sdk

angroid.widget.TextView.java

```
package android.widget;
```

IMHO this is something I don't like about IDE's.  Not to mention merge conflicts /rant.

Hopes this helps someone else.